# Install Socket.io library

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, nowjs-sockets

I have a problem installing the Socket.io library

My server:

- SULinux release 2.0 ( kernel  2.6.18-194.el5PAE )
- nodeJS version is v0.4.5
- NPM version is 1.0.106

I tried to install socket.io using the following command:

```
npm install socket.io
```

that gave the following error message:

```
npm ERR! Failed unpacking /tmp/npm-1322649266839/1322649266839-0.2861799451056868/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! couldn't unpack /tmp/npm-1322649266839/1322649266839-0.2861799451056868/tmp.tgz to /tmp/npm-1322649266839/1322649266839-0.2861799451056868/contents
npm ERR! error installing socket.io-client@0.8.7 Error: `tar "-zmvxpf" "/tmp/npm-1322649266839/1322649266839-0.2861799451056868/tmp.tgz" "-o"`
npm ERR! error installing socket.io-client@0.8.7 failed with 2
```

Why has this error occurred?

Comment: try upgrading Node and NPM, you have very old versions seems

Comment: thank for your response !! ah .. node 0.4.5 is old version? ...
yes. i'll try with lastest version . thank you!!

Comment: Yes you should have installed Node 0.6.3 or at least Node 0.4.12.

Comment: oh.. i just installed nodejs 0.6.3 but ...it don't work ...

Comment: the NPM version was wrong ? the messsage changed.. but still can't install socket.io ... npm ERR! TypeError: Bad argument
npm ERR!     at Object._open (fs.js:223:11)

Comment: Can you update your question with the new errors? They look different that the original ones, yes? Also, try reinstalling npm now that you've upgraded node!

Comment: Could it be permissions issues with /tmp?